# Como fazer um texto refletido com CSS ? (tipo um texto espelhado)

Tags: css, css3

Eu gostaria de fazer um efeito de texto refletido ou texto espelhado apenas com CSS

Tipo essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Alguém tem alguma dica, ou sabe se é possível fazer esse efeito espelhado apenas com CSS ?***

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Mirror</h1>
<h1>Mirror</h1>
```

**OBS:** Não é necessário a letra vermelha no texto. Imagem ilustrativa apenas :) assim como o código, que é apenas um exemplo, não precisa ser com H1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dois elementos distintos pode ferir a semântica do HTML, pois inserirá redundância de conteúdo no documento. Um dos elementos `<h1>` seria meramente estético e não acrescenta em nada ao conteúdo, então não deveria estar no conteúdo. Para evitar isso, pode-se utilizar o elemento `:after`:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
}

h1:after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 80%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 title="Reflection">Reflection</h1>
```

Assim, porém, com CSS no elemento `:after` não há como buscar o conteúdo do elemento pai (não ainda, pelo menos), mas é possível buscar de um atributo deste elemento, tal como o atributo `title`. Importante salientar que mesmo sendo o mesmo conteúdo do elemento, isso não caracterizará redundância, pois semanticamente o texto de `title` será tratado de forma distinta do conteúdo e não haverá problemas em serem iguais.

O atributo `title`, inclusive, é um atributo global, o que significa que todos os elementos do HTML suportam.

---

Um efeito semelhante seria possível utilizando a função [`element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/element) do CSS, porém ela quase não possui suporte atualmente. Com esta função, você consegue definir como plano de fundo outro elemento do documento, então assim você conseguiria gerar a sombra inclusive com todos os efeitos de cores na sua fonte:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background: -moz-element(#foo) ;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

span {
  color: red;
}



.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336; /* Red */
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  Este exemplo só funciona no <strong>Firefox</strong>
</div>

<h1 id="foo">Reflec<span>t</span>ion</h1>
```

O resultado, para quem não tem Firefox (ou está com preguiça de testar) é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Apesar das duas soluções usar praticamente o mesmo CSS, o teu não está funcionando no Firefox. Que bizarro. PS: meu comentário foi antes do EDIT

Comment: @fernandosavio o primeiro deveria funcionar, mas deve ser por eu ter utilizado apenas o prefixo `-webkit`. Verei o que o Firefox não reconheceu e ajustar.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que seria assim. Ainda tem que fazer outros ajustes mais triviais.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1.flip {
margin-top: -3.2rem;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #777);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Mirror</h1>
<h1 class="flip">Mirror</h1>
```

Comment: Consegue fazer isso com o elemento `:after` para não quebrar a semântica do HTML?

Comment: Aí eu não sei como seria.

Comment: Não cheguei a analisar a fundo o que você fez, mas seria algo muito próximo de http://jsfiddle.net/acwoss/yq7pwrvd/. Digo isso porque inserir outro elemento que é meramente estético, não parte do conteúdo, fere a semântica do HTML. Para um leitor de tela, por exemplo, seriam dois títulos para a mesma coisa que falam a mesma coisa, inserindo redundância no documento (não funcionaria com uma letra de outra cor).

Comment: Não respondi com esse mérito. O autor deu um skeleton com dois elementos, apenas modifiquei...

Comment: Faz sentido... :D